How can I make the nested while-loops end if the board is filled?
I've tried quite a few solutions so my program is a bit jumbled, but I still can't figure out a way to check for "_" and end the game if there are none left. I'd actually rather have them break the moment the board fills, but so far nothing seems to work and I don't understand anymore.
Here is my program:
grid = [['0','1','2','3'],['1','_','_','_'], ['2','_','_','_'],['3','_','_','_']]
print("Tic-Tac-Toe")
for row in grid:
    print(row)


for row in grid:
    for cell in row:
        if cell != '_':


            valid_input = False
            while not valid_input:
                x_x = int(input("Choose x-coordinate for x: "))
                x_y = int(input("Choose y-coordinate for x: "))

                if x_x < 1 or x_x > 3 or x_y < 1 or x_y > 3:
                    print("Invalid input for x. Please try again.")
                elif grid[x_x][x_y] != '_':
                    if '_' in grid == False:
                        break
                    else:
                        print("The place is occupied. Choose another place for x.")
                else:
                    grid[x_x][x_y] = 'x'
                    for row in grid:
                        print(row)
                    valid_input = True

            valid_input = False
            while not valid_input:
                o_x = int(input("Choose x-coordinate for o: "))
                o_y = int(input("Choose y-coordinate for o: "))

                if o_x < 1 or o_x > 3 or o_y < 1 or o_y > 3:
                    print("Invalid input for o. Please try again.")
                elif grid[o_x][o_y] != '_':
                    if '_' in grid == False:
                        break
                    else:
                        print("The place is occupied. Choose another place for o.")
                else:
                    grid[o_x][o_y] = 'o'
                    for row in grid:
                        print(row)
                    valid_input = True

I thought this would require you to still try another turn after the game is "done", but then break out of the whole loop. It doesn't. It asks me for another "o" spot indefinitely.

Don't write things like if '_' in grid == False:  Instead just use the much more natural if '_' not in grid:  In general, if you find yourself comparing a known bool to True or False, you're needlessly convoluting your code.

You don't need half of the loops you put in this code. Split the code into functions. One function to validate the input coordinate and other should take valid coordinate, and character they want to insert at coordinate (X or O).
also the index in grid is also pointless.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I hope you're ready to read a really long answer :)
The reason why it indefinitely asks you for another position is because of the way your loops work. You have this on the outside:
for row in grid:
    for cell in row:
        if cell != '_':

What this means is that for every position that isn't _, you'll run the code. There are only 7 spots where this applies (0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), but there are nine empty spots. But then in your code, you have both input for x and input for o. This means that your code actually expects to take in 7 x 2 (7 loops, then 2 inputs one for x and one for o) inputs, but by the time you've reached 9 inputs your board is full, and so it will never take all 14 inputs, thus never ending the program.
But why doesn't it end when the board is full? It's because on the outside, you have two layers of loops. Even though you call break inside of the code, you only break out of the inner loop. Additionally, the way you're checking for _s is wrong because since you have a multilayered list (list inside of list), it won't find any _s because it only looks in the first layer, which has no values except lists. Basically all your program sees is [list, list ,list] and not [1 _ _ _] [2 _ _ _] [3 _ _ _].
Here's some sample code for my version of your program with explanation comments:
grid = [['0','1','2','3'],
        ['1','_','_','_'],
        ['2','_','_','_'],
        ['3','_','_','_']] #Put each row of the grid on new lines to better visualize. As you can see, your x and y inputs are swapped in the code


print("Tic-Tac-Toe")
for row in grid:
    print(row)


turn = 'x' #store whose turn it is
for _ in range(3*3): #your grid is 3 by 3, so that's 9. I put 3*3 because it's easier to see (when you start writing more code you'll want to be able to read through code easily when checking for errors)
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        try: #Use a try and except statement. This is because if a person enters without typing anything, it will cause an error because you can't convert a "nothing" into an integer.
            x = int((input(f"Choose x-coordinate for {turn}: "))) #Use "f" for format to put the variable in the text. Ex. "Choose x-coordinate for x: "
            y = int((input(f"Choose y-coordinate for {turn}: ")))
        except:
            print(f"Invalid input for {turn}. Please try again.")

        if x not in [1, 2, 3] or y not in [1, 2, 3]: #Checks if x or y values are in the list of valid positions. Doing this makes sure people can't input something like "2.5"
            print(f"Invalid input for {turn}. Please try again.")
        elif grid[y][x] != '_': #Swap x and y (Read the comment about your grid variable)
            print(f"The place is occupied. Choose another place for {turn}.")
        else:
            grid[y][x] = turn
            for row in grid:
                print(row)
            valid_input = True
            turn = 'o' if turn == 'x' else 'x' #change the turn to the next player through a one line conditional (You can make this more than one line if you want. It's read as "turn will be x unless turn is already x in which case it will be o")
print("The board is full!")


Additionally, instead of a for loop on the outside, you can also make a variable set to False and use a while loop:
grid = [['0','1','2','3'],
        ['1','_','_','_'],
        ['2','_','_','_'],
        ['3','_','_','_']]


print("Tic-Tac-Toe")
for row in grid:
    print(row)


def fullBoard(): #function to check if the board is full so we can separate code from the main code chunk for better legibility
    for row in grid: #goes through each row in the grid
        for space in row: #goes from each space in the row
            if space == '_': #check if the space is empty
                return False #if any space is empty in the grid, then the board is not full so return False
    return True #if no spaces in the grid are empty, then the board is full so return True


turn, filledBoard = 'x', False #Assign two variables at once. filledBoard is used for the while loop
while not filledBoard: 
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        try:
            x = int((input(f"Choose x-coordinate for {turn}: ")))
            y = int((input(f"Choose y-coordinate for {turn}: ")))
        except:
            print(f"Invalid input for {turn}. Please try again.")

        if x not in [1, 2, 3] or y not in [1, 2, 3]: 
            print(f"Invalid input for {turn}. Please try again.")
        elif grid[int(y)][int(x)] != '_':
            print(f"The place is occupied. Choose another place for {turn}.")
        else:
            grid[int(y)][int(x)] = turn
            for row in grid:
                print(row)
            valid_input = True
            turn = 'o' if turn == 'x' else 'x'
    filledBoard = fullBoard() #Call our function to check if the board is full every single time a player makes a move

print("The board is full!")

